# PHP. go to next page after form insert to db

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, redirect

I have a page where I insert from form to database-table and would like to get to another page when insert is done.
Table gets my form-input but I end up on the form-page (probably because of the `['PHP_SELF']`) but I am hoping this can be changed. My best thought until now is this:

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!$conn)
    {
        die("Something is not working correctly" . mysqli_error($conn));
    } else {
    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO table (name, user VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[user]')";
    mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql_insert);
    **header("location: http://mydomain/myresult.php");**
    }
}
```

and this is my form "header" - if that gives anybody a clue

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="insert">
```

PS. I am fully aware that I have no validation, cleaning, washing of input at this point but that's another matter.

Comment: @user3783243 the names have been changed to protect the innocent. SORRY missing a parenthesis before USER (wish I could change it). Right about multi_query (momentary lapse!) but as I said: not sanitized for this question. Only the (missing) redirect is my interest.

Comment: Looks fine to me. NOTE: header will only redirect if nothing has been printed on to the page so best action would be to have the if statement at the top of ur page

Comment: @MohammadC So when you say print? I have all the html/css below on my page and a php-date-thing to fill out some input-fields. Is there another way to say: when sql is done go to another page? My if()-script is "waiting" for the submit to happen and then do it's thing

Comment: So the code posted is already at the top if the page and it is still not redirecting to the page u want.

Comment: It's best to use `die(header("Location: http://something"));` (the die) because otherwise additional code can execute on this page.

Comment: I "only" have a log-in-verification (if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])...) and my connection statement above the php I added here. Below I have the form, some text and a couple of php echo date-things.

Comment: @AaronSaray: adding die() didn't change the behaviour. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-araound. It probably seems less than elegant but I hope it doesn't post a serious issue(?)
Adding this to the top gets me to my header/redirect/location when $_POST is not empty (which was exactly what I was after. Sorry for wasting your time - and many thanks for the tips. **The header-as-first-thing-on-page was a good clue**. Thank you @Mohammad C

```
<?php if(!empty($_POST['submit'])){
    header("location: http://mydomain/mypresult.php"); } ?>
```